# Implode an array in php with specified type

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3, php-5.5

I have this array :

```
Array
(
   [0] =>
   [1] =>
   [2] => test1
   [3] => test2
)
```

Now I make :

```
if(!empty($a_data)){
        $a_return = array(implode(',"', array_filter($a_data)));
    }
```

And I get this :

```
aReturn": [
   "test1,\"test2"
]
```

But I want to get :

```
aReturn": [
   "test1","test2"
]
```

Can you help me please ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: ," why are u using this? why not `array(implode(',', array_filter($a_data)));`?

Comment: So you're converting this array to json to display it? Learn how json works if you're going to do that; but consider imploding on `'","'`

Answer (score 1):

```
    $value  = array_values(array_filter($a_data));
    var_dump($value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here no need to store comma separated values again in an array you can use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function here which will return the all values inside the array than you just need to use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for your desired output as:

```
<?php
$a_data = array('','','test','test2');
$a_return = array_values(array_filter($a_data));
echo json_encode($a_return);
?>
```

**Output**: `["test","test2"]`

And if you still want to use your code than you just need to use [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) for strip slashes as:

```
<?php
$a_data = array('','','test','test2');
$a_return = array(implode('","', array_filter($a_data)));
echo stripslashes(json_encode($a_return));
?>
```

**Output:** `["test","test2"]`